# Modify form value via ASP.NET MVC Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to modify the quantity of product added to cart via an MVC Action Filter. This is what I have but it's not working:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var settings = _settingService.LoadSetting<RRGamesBaseSettings>();
        var customer = _workContext.CurrentCustomer;         

        if (customer.IsInCustomerRole(settings.ResellerRoleSystemName))
        {
            var productId = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.ActionParameters["productId"]);
            var formCollection = new FormCollection(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Fo‌​rm);
            var productService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IRRGamesProductService>();
            var product = productService.GetProductById(productId);
            int quantity = 0;
            string fieldName = string.Format("addtocart_{0}.EnteredQuantity", productId);

            int.TryParse(formCollection[fieldName], out quantity);

            if (product != null)
            {
                if (quantity < product.CaseQuantity)
                {
                    quantity = product.CaseQuantity;
                    formCollection[fieldName] = quantity.ToString();
                }
            }                
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

when I set formCollection[formKey] to the new quantity, it doesn't update the form value when it goes to the controller action.

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do. You initialize a `new FormCollection` and make changes to it (not the `Request.Fo‌​rm`). In any case this should be done in custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: this action filter intercepts an add to cart method and changes the quantity  value in the form. I need to use an action filter because I am doing this in a plugin so I don't modify the original source code of the app.

Comment: You not changing the value in `Request.Form` - your changing it in a copy  of it that you have made (your variable `formCollection`)

Comment: is there a way to change the original value?

Comment: also, it's Nopcommerce, the actionresult does not have a viewmodel,
public ActionResult AddProductToCart_Details(int productId, int shoppingCartTypeId, FormCollection form)

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and it was simple

```
formCollection.Set(fieldName, quantity.ToString());

filterContext.ActionParameters["form"] = formCollection;
```